# Palindrome program help c++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble flipping around the string in my palindrome program. What I want is to enter "cat" for example, and get out "tac", but when I run it, it will not display the reversed string, and the program stops working. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
string phrase1,phrase2;
int len;

cout<<"Please enter a word or phrase: ";
cin>>phrase1;
len = phrase1.length();

for(int a=1;a<=len;a++){
    phrase2[len-a] = phrase1[a-1];
}
cout<<endl<<phrase1<<endl<<phrase2<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ palindrome" to find many examples on Palindrome.

Comment: phrase1 works and will display "cat", but it will not display phrase2. Instead I will get a dialogue box saying the .exe program has stopped working.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews there are two types of questions. One is "how do I do X?" and the second is "What's wrong with my code specifically?". Your suggestion is good for the first, but this question is the second type.

Comment: You could also use a *debugger* to single step through your program and find out where the issue is.  Many professionals do this rather than posting their programs on StackOverflow.

Comment: `string phrase1; cin >> phrase1; copy(phrase1.rbegin(), phrase1.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout));`..but obligatory side note: `using namespace std;` is bad-- you probably want `std::string...`, and so on instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to resize phrase2 to the right length first.

```
phrase2.resize(len);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write this:

```
for(int a=1;a<=len;a++){
    phrase2[len-a] = phrase1[a-1];
}
```

You're trying to fill phrase2 with the reverse of phrase1. But you never allocated memory for phrase2 in the first place!

Since this is a palindrome, you know that you want phrase2 to have the same size phrase1 has, so you can write `phrase2.resize(len);` beforehand.